# Resource cannot be resolved or is not a field?

Tags: android

I copy pasted everything from a tutorial, 3 of them saved, but weird thing happened.

It said my `Chronometer` and button cannot be resolved or is not a field.

StopWatch.java

```
package com.example.stopwatch2;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;

public class StopWatch extends Activity {
    Chronometer mChronometer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_stop_watch);Button button;

        mChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer);

        // Watch for button clicks.
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        button.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        button.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        button.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);

    }

    View.OnClickListener mStartListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.start();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener mStopListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.stop();
        }
    };

    View.OnClickListener mResetListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
        }
    };


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_stop_watch, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

activity_stop_watch.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:padding="4dip"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Chronometer android:id="@+id/chronometer"
        android:format="@string/chronometer_initial_format"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:paddingBottom="30dip"
        android:paddingTop="30dip"
        />

    <Button android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start">
        <requestFocus />
    </Button>

    <Button android:id="@+id/stop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Stop">
    </Button>

    <Button android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reset">
    </Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

string.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:xliff="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
    <string name="hello">Hello World, StopWatch!</string>
    <string name="app_name">StopWatch</string>
    <string name="chronometer_initial_format">Initial format:<xliff:g id="initial-format">%</xliff:g></string>

</resources>
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?

Comment: Just right click on your project and clean and build the project

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning your project. Right click on your project and say 'clean'. Then try running your app again.

Also, another tip. Don't use the same variable names for all the buttons. Use different names like this:

```
// Watch for button clicks.
        buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
        button.setOnClickListener(mStartListener);

        buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        button.setOnClickListener(mStopListener);

        buttonReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        button.setOnClickListener(mResetListener);
```

Your code will be easier to manage and debug in the long run.